# Group rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, rows, pandas-groupby

**Background:** I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'day': ["t", "m", "m", "w", "t", "m","w"], 
     'month': ["01", "01", "01", "01", "02","02","02"], 
     'count': [1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I group by `day` and `month`:

```
df.groupby(by=['day','month']).count()
```

**Output:**

```
day  month count    
m    01     2
     02     1
t    01     1
     02     1
w    01     1
     02     1
```

From here, I would like to organize the data to obtain the following output:

**Desired Output:**

```
day  month count    
m    01     2
t    01     1
w    01     1
m    02     1
t    02     1
w    02     1
```

I tried `df.sort_values('month')`  and `df.sort_values('day')` but it doesn't quite give me what I am looking for

**Question**: What line(s) of code do I need to add to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. It only happens to get the day ordering correct, but you might want to convert them to actually 0-6 for days of the week if you have more days later.

```
df.groupby(by=['day','month'], as_index=False).count().sort_values(by=['month', 'day'])

    day month   count
0   m   01  2
2   t   01  1
4   w   01  1
1   m   02  1
3   t   02  1
5   w   02  1
```

Comment: If you don't want the original indices, use the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort_index` with `level` parameter:

```
df.groupby(by=['day','month']).count().sort_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
           count
day month       
m   01         2
t   01         1
w   01         1
m   02         1
t   02         1
w   02         1
```

and reset_index if you wish.

```
df.groupby(by=['day','month']).count().sort_index(level=1).reset_index()

  day month  count
0   m    01      2
1   t    01      1
2   w    01      1
3   m    02      1
4   t    02      1
5   w    02      1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `groupby` automatically sorts the index.  Instead, switch the order you are grouping by then swap the levels

```
df.groupby(by=['month', 'day']).count().swaplevel(0, 1)

           count
day month       
m   01         2
t   01         1
w   01         1
m   02         1
t   02         1
w   02         1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'day': ["t", "m", "m", "w", "t", "m","w"], 
     'month': ["01", "01", "01", "01", "02","02","02"], 
     'count': [1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.groupby(['day','month']).count().reset_index()
```

> Output(you can now apply sort()

```
    day month count
0   m    01    2

1   m    02    1

2   t    01    1

3   t    02    1

4   w    01    1

5   w    02    1
```